# PosgreSQL odbc ssl connection, libpq connection parameter error:invalid connection option "{sslrootcert"

Tags: postgresql, ssl, centos, odbc

I am having problems with odbc psql link on centos8 and with **postgres-odbc version 10.3**(this one was the default one in the repository)

I have defined my ssl cert files as such

```
pqopt={sslrootcert=/etc/ssl/certs/db_ssl_cert/client.crt \
sslcert=/etc/ssl/certs/db_ssl_cert/postgresql_client.crt \
sslkey=/etc/ssl/certs/db_ssl_cert/postgresql_client.key}
```

But I keep getting error(when using isql), even though I can connect using psql

```
[08001][unixODBC]libpq connection parameter error:invalid connection option "{sslrootcert"
```

I get this error no matter what I put in front of the first `=` sign.

Should the certificates be in `~/.postgresql/` directory?

What is the problem? On my windows machine I input parameters as above and no problems with the driver version **11.0**, should I simply update the driver to the latest version, or what would be the solution as `pgopt` was supported from 9.6 `postgres-odbc`?

Comment: Could you link us to whatever documentation/example/tutorial you are following?

Comment: Forums from posgresql, contacting the developers, there is no official documentation that would cover ssl odbc connections.